# Expected network bandwidth of B-series virtual machines

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

What is the expected network bandwidth of B-series VMs? Checked documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-general) and found nothing about this. So I'm wondering is there any official source of this or I'll have to test it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I'm wondering is there any official source of this or I'll have to
>   test it myself?

You could use `iperf3` to test bandwidth between your VMs.

More information about this you could check this [blog](https://azure-in-action.blog/2017/01/01/azure-vm-network-bandwidth-tests/).